# How to select only last rows that satisfies conditions?

Tags: mysql, select

I'm trying to select rows where x=5, but x changes constantly. So I have such a table:

```
 id    x
----  ---
 1     5
 2     6
 3     4
 4     5
 5     5
```

So I want to perform a query like `"SELECT * FROM table WHERE x=5 AND _???_;"` so that it returns rows 4 & 5 but *not* row 1.

In other words, I want to get the rows where x had this value most recently. I hope I made myself clear. Thanks!

edit:
Number of entries after x got the last value my change. I mean the table could also be like this:

```
 id    x
----  ---
 1     5
 2     6
 3     4
 4     5
 5     1
 6     5
 7     5
...    5
100    5
101    5
```

in this case it should return rows [6-101].

Answer (score 2):

Following wil get recent row

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE x=5 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

Comment: yes but this will still return 5,4, and 1 , right?
I want to automatically stop where x changed , so that it never returns 1.

Answer (score 1):

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bcf86/3)

```
select * from t t1
where 
x=(select x from t order by id desc limit 1)
and
not exists
(select x from t where id>t1.id and x<>t1.x)
```

or
[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bcf86/9)

```
select * from t t1
where 
x=(select x from t order by id desc limit 1)
and
id>=
(select max(id) from t 
  where x<>
   (select x from t order by id desc limit 1)
)
```

Select what is faster on your base.